# Blazor WASM inject settings into a Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, payment-processing, razor-class-library

My intent is to create a payment processing service I can bolt onto the side of any website. My issue is injecting settings, such as a Stripe Public Key, a Paypal Merchant Id, and the specific url on the server to send the token and to charge stripe.

This is simplified for this question (and the `Payments` projects will end up being dll's), but the project structure looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

The WebApp is the ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WASM project template. `WebApp.Client` has dependencies on `Payments.Shared` and `Payments.Ui` while `WebApp.Server` has a dependency on `Payments.Backend` as well (for Stripe charge response etc models).

Since I want to use this Payments service on any site, and since these will be different for every site, I'll need to set the props in `PaymentSettings.cs` at startup.

Is there a way to do this? I only plan on using with Blazor WASM websites, if that matters.

I feel like I might be able to pass these settings down to the `WebApp.Client` through `string[] args` in `Program.cs`'s `Main` method:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //omitted for brevity

    //relevant line here
    builder.Services
      .AddSingleton(sp => new Payments.Shared.Infrastructure.PaymentSettings(args));

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

and then from there into the constructor for `PaymentSettings.cs`:

```
public class PaymentSettings
{
    public PaymentSettings(string[] args)
    {
        //set props from args
    }

    public string PaypalMerchantId { get; set; }
    public string StripeKey { get; set; }
    public string ChargeStripeUrl { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't see any way to do this from the `WebApp.Server` project.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, I mean, if I can at least inject the base url of `WebApp.Server` into the `Payments.Shared` project, I can then run a get request for the rest of it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ***was*** overthinking it. Since it's all public info, I just hard-coded the info into `Program.cs` in the `WebApp.Client`:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //omitted for brevity

    string stripeKey = "Hello dolly";
    string paypalId = "How ye be";
    string chargeStripeUrl = "https://all-about-dolly.com/chargeIt";

    //relevant line here
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new PaymentSettings 
    {
        StripeKey = stripeKey,
        PaypalMerchantId = paypalId,
        ChargeStripeUrl = chargeStripeUrl
    });

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Might not be best practices, but it works for me.